# First time Ubuntu user looking fir a basic image editing software

Tags: 14.04

I have just installed Ubuntu as dual boot on my laptop and everything runs well. I'm looking for a simple image editor. Till now I have been using the default photos app in win 8.1 and am comfortable and satisfied with the results. Is there something similar in Ubuntu? I have installed Gimp but the learning curve is steep for me and I need something which shows me a handful of preset settings/filters. You know what I'm talking about if you have used the windows photos app or snapseed

Answer (score 0):

Hey I also faced the same issue.
Polarr works fine for me. It should help you also. 
You can download it from the Ubuntu Software or the polarr website.

https://www.polarr.co/editor/0

or use

sudo snap install polarr